# onchange event not handling button click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on saving textarea value on browser refresh. When there's a change to textarea by keyboard events, the value gets stored in local storage. However, When the textarea value gets changed indirectly...like button clicks, the value doesn't get saved. That's the problem, So, I changed my event handler from `onkeyup` to `onchange`. Still, This remains a problem. Do anyone have a better idea for this. Here's the code -

```html
<textarea id="thetext" class="" value="Write some value, and off focus this input. Refresh the browser, and see the text getting saved." onchange="saveValue(this);"></textarea><br/><br/>
<button id="thebutton" onclick="change()">Change</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById("thetext").value = getSavedValue("thetext");

    function saveValue(e){

        var id = e.id;  
        var val = e.value;  
        localStorage.setItem(id, val);

    }

    function getSavedValue (v) {

        if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
            return "";
        }

        return localStorage.getItem(v);

    };

    function change() {

        document.getElementById("thetext").value = "This value doesn't get saved if there's no keyboard action. But I want this to get saved on button click."

    }
</script>
<style>
textarea{height:100px;width:100%}
</style>
```

***Edit - Above code is working well on my environment.***

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `saveValue` in your `change` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do in easy way

```
function change() {
  let newValue = "This value doesn't get saved if there's no keyboard action. But I want this to get saved on button click."
  
  var event = new Event('input');
  thetext.dispatchEvent(event);

  // or 
  // document.getElementById("thetext").value = newValue;
  // localStorage.setItem("thetext", newValue );
  
}
```

or complex usinng `Object.defineProperty`

```js
thetext = document.getElementById("thetext")
thetext.value = getSavedValue("thetext");

function saveValue(e) {
  console.log(e)
  var id = e.id;
  var val = e.value;
  localStorage.setItem(id, val);
}

function getSavedValue(v) {
  return localStorage.getItem(v) || "";
}

function change() {
  document.getElementById("thetext").value = "This value doesn't get saved if there's no keyboard action. But I want this to get saved on button click."
}

function monitorValue(element, property) {
  let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(element), property);
  Object.defineProperty(element, property, {
    get: function() {
      return descriptor.get.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    set: function() {
      descriptor.set.apply(this, arguments);
      // create and dispatch input event
      var event = new Event('input');
      element.dispatchEvent(event);
      return this.value;
    }
  });
}

monitorValue(thetext, "value")
```

```html
<style>textarea{height:80vh;width:100%}</style>
<textarea id="thetext" class="" 
value="Write some value, and off focus this input. Refresh the browser, and see the text getting saved." 
oninput="saveValue(this);
"></textarea><br/><br/>

<button id="thebutton" onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is that, the `<textarea>` value be stored in the `localStorage` every time it's changed.

I'd prefer defining a setter property on the textarea.

```
var ta = document.getElementById('thetext');

Object.defineProperty(ta, 'savedValue' , {
    set: (value)=> {
        ta.savedValue = ta.value = value;
        localStorage.setItem(ta.id, value);
    }
};

thebutton.addEventListener('click', (evt)=> {
    ta.savedValue = 'my sample click value';
});

ta.addEventListener('change', (evt)=> {
    ta.savedValue = evt.target.value;
};
```

Comment: Yes, My code works when the textarea is changed by keyboard actions. However, When somewhen changes the value by button click, the value doesn't get saved until keyboard action is applied. I tried your thing but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you initialize `thebutton` with `document.getElementById('thebutton')` ?